# Change LIMIT in MySQL without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So basically what I want is when you click on a link, the **$limit** variable in my MySQL Query should be increased by 10 without refreshing the page. I know there are many similar questions, but I just couldn't work it out.

#### index.php

```
<?php  
$limit = 10;  

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT $limit");       
?>

<a href="#" id="more">Show more...</a>
```

#### javascript.js

```
$('#more').click(function(){
    //Now here some jQuery / AJAX that changes the PHP $limit variable?
});
```

Is this possible in any way? I know that Javascript is on the client and PHP on the server side and my MySQL is up to date so the variable inside the query works. The title could've been 'How the change a PHP variable with jQuery' aswell, but if that's not possible I really need another solution to dynamically change the query (maybe even with refreshing).

Thanks :)

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. consider using a parameterized query.

Comment: You could send the value as a parameter, or put it in a cookie if you want the value to persist across page loads.

Comment: Use DataTable js plugin https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Daniel I don't see any user input in the code. And @Replay, you should learn `mysqli` or `PDO`, as `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated in PHP.

Comment: You need http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ when you send your variable to server then return some json or values HTML directly. But I think JSON will be better for your need. Then When it is returned I mean Javascript Callback function run then just put values on places. You need to Append values or just replace HTML. And After this process you will understand ajax better. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it, Thanks for the help guys! :)

#### index.php

```
<?php
$limit = $_POST['limit'];

include('/connect_db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT $limit";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
?>

<a href="#" id="more">Show more...</a>
```

#### javascript.js

```
var limit = 10;

$('#more').click(function() {
    limit += 10;

    ajax();

});

var news = document.getElementById('news');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit},
    success: function(data){
        news.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot to learn mate!

First look into AJAX (including jQuery if you don't know already). With both you can do "dynamical" calls / updating to content on a webpage (no refreshing). Second look into PHP 'mysql_real_escape_string' and PDO and understand what "SQL injections" are to better security your database and server.

Comment: I sure have a lot to learn, but that's what I'm doing right now ;) I replaced all my `SQL` with `PDO` and it's working perfectly. I also implemented `AJAX` in my code now, but the AJAX doesn't seem to be working properly...Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Make sure you are either setting a "get" or "post" request in the AJAX code (it's a parameter) and that are retrieving that in the PHP code itself too! Besides that add in some error and success callback hooks  in the AJAX code too. That will help for debugging and error fail back code to trigger.

All referenced from:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (Callback Function Queues).

A lot of trial and error until you get it :] and good to hear you're using PDO! :D MySQL PHP functions are actually deprecated, so that's a good step forward in good code practice!

Answer (score 0):

You will need use ajax (and JSON for a good job), you have code examples here :

http://www.lennu.net/2012/06/25/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple